# react-native-video: How to support audio/video data comming from a blob?

Tags: react-native-video

I am using react-native-video package to play audio/video on my App. It work fine for URLs.

```js
import Video from 'react-native-video';


 <Video source={{uri: 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4'  }}
```

I have some audio/video files saved in a DB as blob data. How can I display them? I tried following way, but no luck with it.

```js
var audioURL =  "data:audio/mp3;base64," + this.state.dataSource[i].contentData ; 
// This content data has whats comming from db
 <Video source={{uri:  audioURL  }}
```

Comment: Hi,
Did you find a solution? 
I'm looking for a wat to play blob video in React Native too

Comment: Hi @Chinthaka 
Did you find a solution to this problem?